# Using dojo/text! from within Typescript class

Tags: typescript, dojo

I've seen some examples that imply that it's possible to do this, but I have not been successful. I'm using Typescript 2.7.2. Our project has many extensions of dijit._Widget and dijit._TemplatedMixin written in JavaScript. We're gradually moving to Typescript. I've created an interface that extends these two classes (and others) with a constructor in a d.ts file and extend that interface in a class written in Typescript using AMD class definition syntax. I'm declaring an extension of this class and am trying to use dojo/text! to load an html template in the extension. This is form.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../../../node_modules/dojo-typings/dojo/1.11/dojo.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../../../node_modules/dojo- typings/dijit/1.11/dijit.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/dom.generated.d.ts" />

declare namespace com {
  namespace foo {
    namespace bar {
      namespace web {
        namespace components {
          namespace form {
            interface ModelObjectMainFormView extends dijit._Widget, dijit._TemplatedMixin, dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin, dojo.Evented {
              on(type: string | dojo.ExtensionEvent, func: dojo.EventListener | Function): dojo.WatchHandle;
              emit(type: string | dojo.ExtensionEvent, ...events: any[]): boolean;
            }

            interface ModelObjectFormViewConstructor {
              new (args: Array<any>);
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is modules.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="index.d.ts" />

declare module 'com/foo/bar/web/components/form/ModelObjectMainFormView' {
  type ModelObjectMainFormView = com.foo.bar.web.components.form.ModelObjectMainFormView;
  const ModelObjectMainFormView: com.foo.bar.web.components.form.ModelObjectFormViewConstructor;
  export = ModelObjectMainFormView;
}

declare module "dojo/text!*" {
  var _: string;
  export default _;
}
```

This is the AMD declaration of the extension:

```
import declare = require("dojo/_base/declare");
import ModelObjectMainFormView = require("com/foo/bar/web/components/form/ModelObjectMainFormView");

class TSModelObjectMainFormView {
  inherited: (args: Object) => any;
}

var exp = declare("com.foo.bar.web.components.form.TSModelObjectMainFormView", [ModelObjectMainFormView], new TSModelObjectMainFormView());
export = exp;
```

This is the extension that tries to use dojo/text!:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="dojo/text!com/foo/bar/web/workItems/configuration/forms/templates/ConfigurationWorkItemMainFormView.html" name="template" />
import * as aspect from 'dojo/aspect';
import * as domAttr from 'dojo/dom-attr';
import * as domClass from 'dojo/dom-class';
import * as domConstruct from 'dojo/dom-construct';
import * as lang from 'dojo/_base/lang';
import ModernizationUtil = require('com/foo/bar/rtc/web/util/ModernizationUtil');
import MimeTypes = require('com/foo/bar/web/scm/MimeTypes');
import * as TSModelObjectMainFormView from '../../../components/form/TSModelObjectMainFormView';
// import * as template from "dojo/text!com/foo/bar/web/workItems/configuration/forms/templates/ConfigurationWorkItemMainFormView.html";
let template: string;

export class ConfigurationWorkItemMainFormView extends TSModelObjectMainFormView {
  templateString = template;

  constructor(args?: any) {
    super(args);
  }
}
```

I use the ams-dependency because the import of dojo/text! fails at run time when it attempts to get the module. It can't find it. The dojo code generates some unique id based on the url of the resource with dojo/text! prepended, then a number, then an !, then the rest of the url. It looks in a collection of modules expecting to find it on the line of code that does the import, and that fails. Reports module not found.
With the ams-dependency, template is actually defined in the source as a string, and it contains the HTML loaded by dojo/text! when the class constructor is called. The problem is, the call to super() in the constructor must be the first line of code, and the super constructor depends on templateString already having been established. Of course, the instance variable templateString does not get assigned the value of template until after the return of the constructor.
I would very much appreciate help on this. If I can provide more info, just let me know. Thanks to any and all.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this to work by making the following changes:
To the AMD declaration of the extension:

```
class TSModelObjectMainFormView {
  templateString: string;
  inherited: (args: Object) => any;

  constructor(args?: any) {
    if (args && args.templateString) {
      this.templateString = args.templateString;
      this.inherited(arguments);
    }
  }
}
```

And to the Typescript class extending TSModelObjectMainFormView:

```
constructor(args: any) {
  super(lang.mixin(args, {templateString: template}));
}
```

I'm sure there's a better way. I would love to receive some advice. This is still using the amd-dependency, which, as I understand it, has been deprecated.